# Correct scope reference to object within window object

Tags: javascript

Since my previous question was not answered i thought i give it another try only formulated better.

```
(function() { 

    var ns = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){

        ns['someName'] = 'na' + i; 

        //Logs ns0 and ns1 like i want
        console.log(ns["someName"]);

        window.addEventListener('load', function(){

            //Logs ns1 twice
            console.log(ns["someName"]);


        });

    }



})();
```

So the question being how to keep the correct scope within the window eventListener.
Thanks!

Comment: Not all users of this site are guys.

Comment: its a general use of words sorry you felt offended

Answer (score 0):

You can use the magic of closures

```
(function(value) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){

        //Logs ns1 twice
        console.log(value);

    });
})(ns["someName"]);
```

Defined an inline function and called it inmediatly using the current value for `ns["someName"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() { 
    var ns = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        ns['someName'] = 'na' + i; 
        console.log(ns["someName"]);
        (function(value){
           window.addEventListener('load', function(){
                console.log(value);
           });
        }(ns['someName'] ));
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the code to show how you can 'preserve' the scope within each load-callback-function. You can use a self-execution function to return a closure:

```
(function() { 

    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        window.addEventListener('load', (function(i){
            return function(evt) {
                // i is as expected: 0 and then 1
                console.log(i);
                // the variable 'evt' contains the event-object
            };
        })(i));

    }

})();
```

Comment: you'll lose your event reference with this approach already tried it, thanks!

Comment: @user3539582: I changed the code: just add a parameter (called 'evt') to the returned closure and you still have the event object ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the help of closures

```
(function() { 
    var ns = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        ns['someName'] = 'na' + i; 
        console.log(ns["someName"]);
        (function(value){
           window.addEventListener('load', function(){

                   return (function(){  
                        console.log(value);
                      })()
           });
        }(ns["someName"]));
    }
})();
```

This will do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your input much appreciated! ive been battling this for a two days now and i was about to pull out my hair.

here is the final code:

```
(function() { 

  for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){

    var ns = {};

    ns['someName' + i] = 'ns' + i; 

    //Logs ns0 and ns1 like i want
    console.log(ns);

   (function(value) {

        window.addEventListener('load', function(event){

            //Logs ns0 and ns1 like i want
            console.log(value);

            //preseved my events
            console.log(event);

        });

    })(ns); 

  }

})();
```